# Mathematical English in PDE's type paper

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, article-writing

I am trying to write some materials in PDE content. However, my English is not very good. Do we have some PDE's type papers or books that is well-written? I am reading the book by Trinduger, but I can not search words in the PDF document. Do you have some good suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I like the book 'Partial Differential Equations by Lawrence C. Evans'. This is quite a theoretical book if that's what you're after?

Comment: Thanks! It is a well-written book!

Comment: I found it very well written! It has a nice appendix section at the back of the book explaining some concepts of measure theory, functional analysis, and more if you needed to brush up on some topics.